# Transaction causing activity to recall Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, transactions, firebase

When I click my **rate_btn** to start this transaction function.

It works fine but in the process it re-run my class activity one more time (my class activity re-runs every time transaction is used) therefore resetting everything like my **msg_ID**.

For example, my **msg_ID** changes (due to using random) every time this class activity is called, so when I run transaction it works but in return it ran the class activity also therefore changing my **msg_ID** aswell.

Here's a scenario:

> so when click this "rate" button it does the rating
>   on the current **msg_ID** but when I click on it again, it rates a different
>   **msg_ID** because of my get random **msg_ID**. I think this is caused when
>   I call the onComplete method.

*When I click the **rate_btn***

[image: vote up the first key]

*Now the class re-run and I click on the **rate_btn** again.*

[image: vote up second key]

It votes up the first **msg_id** then when I click the **rate_btn** again it votes up the second key (Because of it re-called class activity and the **msg_id** changed)

Here's the code for transaction:

```
rate_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
        Firebase upvoteref = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/"+msgID+"/upvotes"); 

        upvoteref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(final MutableData currentData) {
                if (currentData.getValue() == null) {
                    currentData.setValue(1);
                } else {
                    currentData.setValue((Long) currentData.getValue() + 1);
                }

                return Transaction.success(currentData);
            }

            public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
                if (firebaseError != null) {
                    System.out.println("Firebase counter increment failed.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Firebase counter increment succeeded.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the code for retrieving the random id:

```
    String msgID; //this variable is declare at the start of the class as a global variable.

    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/"+msgID); 

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> ds = snapshot.getChildren();

            //getting maximum number of children
            long allNum = snapshot.getChildrenCount();
            int maxNum = (int)allNum;

            //getting the random integer from number of children
            int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(maxNum);

            Iterator<DataSnapshot> ids = ds.iterator();

            int count = 0;

            //has next will check if there are values in the next iteration , while count is used as a position substitute.
            while(ids.hasNext() && count < randomNum) {
                ids.next();
                count ++; // used as positioning.
            }           

            Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) ids.next().getValue(); // ids will take the value in the iterator (iterate at key) 
            //getting the message from the key
            msgID = newPost.get("id").toString();
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Message ID changes every every time transaction is called, this is because of `addValueEventListener` (it accept the changes when calling transaction). Therefore to solve this I add `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener` and it worked.

For Example:

```
 ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> ds = snapshot.getChildren();

        //getting maximum number of children
        long allNum = snapshot.getChildrenCount();
        int maxNum = (int)allNum;

        //getting the random integer from number of children
        int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(maxNum);

        Iterator<DataSnapshot> ids = ds.iterator();

        int count = 0;

        //has next will check if there are values in the next iteration , while count is used as a position substitute.
        while(ids.hasNext() && count < randomNum) {
            ids.next();
            count ++; // used as positioning.
        }           

        Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) ids.next().getValue(); // ids will take the value in the iterator (iterate at key) 
        //getting the message from the key
        msgID = newPost.get("id").toString();
    }`
```