# Why does OnComplete recall the class activity? Firebase Android

Tags: android, transactions, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Every time I use Transaction, when it calls `OnComplete`. The `OnComplete` method calls my whole class activity again.

Can someone explain? Here's the code:

```
rate_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
    Firebase upvoteref = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/"+msgID+"/upvotes"); 

    upvoteref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(final MutableData currentData) {
            if (currentData.getValue() == null) {
                currentData.setValue(1);
            } else {
                currentData.setValue((Long) currentData.getValue() + 1);
            }

            return Transaction.success(currentData);
        }

        public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
            if (firebaseError != null) {
                System.out.println("Firebase counter increment failed.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Firebase counter increment succeeded.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How about setting a breakpoint on the method and then checking the callstack to see where it is called from?

Comment: Answered it here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022566/transaction-causing-activity-to-recall-firebase-android